# Resistance of infinite resistor network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I was looking through Physics Olympiad problems and I found this. This question asks: 
**Find the equivalent resistance between the points A and B, all the arms have equal resistance $R$**.

I understand that the network is self similar and I can take the resistance of the whole network as a Variable and the solve for it, but I can't seem to understand how to do so for A and B. Any hints or suggestions to how to approach this would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance. 
[image]

Comment: Is it infinite in all directions?

Comment: No, just along its length(as per the dotted lines).

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301)

Comment: Well this is not a homework question but one from an Olympiad which I was curious about and it's about a conceptual difficulty on how to solve these problems with infinite network of resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint. Would it make any difference if you joined (with a wire of zero resistance) each junction on the top row to the junction directly below it on the bottom row?

Comment: Geometrical symmetry -> Current pattern symmetry & Resistance symmetry -> Potential Symmetry

Comment: For a wire with zero resistance I think it would make a difference as then current flow through the wires then instead of taking the math through the network. Correct me if I'm wrong and please elaborate.

Comment: By symmetry a junction on the bottom line is at the same potential as the junction directly above it on the top line. Therefore you may merge these corresponding points, to make a 'ladder' consisting of just the top line modified resistor values), the middle line (with resistor values unchanged) and with the bridging resistances modified) . I've left the values of the modified resistors for you to decide – it's very easy to do.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why my answer attracted a negative vote. Questioner asked for hints and suggestions and was given a hint. Follow it through and the question becomes much simpler to deal with.

Comment: @PhilipWood Not my vote, but for questions that are in flagrant defiance of the homework guidance, providing answers can be seen as encouraging future questions of similar quality.

Comment: EP I take your point, but I think this is a rather special case. This question calls for a use of principles (two in particular) that may be of interest to some of the wider community; it is not a routine homework-type question. Indeed it isn't homework at all, though I know that your case isn't damaged by this distinction.